# Spring Boot not starting Jetty when using bootRun

Tags: spring, jetty, spring-boot

In our current app we want to use Jetty instead of Tomcat in our Spring Boot app. As i read in the documentation excluding tomcat and introducing Jetty would be enough.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
}
```

But when i try to run the app with using:

```
# gradle bootRun
```

Tomcat is indeed gone, but Jetty is not started and the application just terminates with any noticeable error. Any hints on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Works well for me with Boot `1.1.0.RELEASE`.

You need to run Gradle command with `--info`(`--debug`) hint to get more info what's going on.